# Method append does not exist on Laravel pagination

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5.5

I'm having some trouble using the following code. It looks like I've forgotten how to Laravel after taking a break over christmas

`{{ $portalEntries->append(Input::except('page'))->links() }}`

Error Exception

```
Method append does not exist. (View: /home/sites/mydomain.com/resources/views/portal/page.blade.php)
```

Here is the code where I get the variable `$portalEntries`

```
public function getEntries($paginate = 20, $deleted = false)
{
    $query = PortalEntry::select(DB::raw('portal_entries.*'))
        ->where('portal_entries.portal_page_id', $this->id)
        ->orderBy('portal_entries.id', 'desc');

    if($deleted) {
        $query->where('portal_entries.deleted', 1);
    }
    else {
        $query->where('portal_entries.deleted', 0);
    }

    if(request()->has('search')) {
        $query->join('portal_entries_values', 'portal_entries.id', '=', 'portal_entries_values.portal_entries_id');
        $query->where('value', 'like', '%'.request("search").'%');

        if(request()->input('search_column', 'all') !== 'all') {

            $query->where('portal_entries_values.portal_page_columns_id', request()->input('search_column'));
        }
    }

    return $query->paginate($paginate);
}
```

Comment: Is it `appends()` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Replace append with appends**. [check this link for details](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination)

Try this

```
{{ $portalEntries->appends(Input::except('page'))->links() }}
```